# C# web form Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am working on a C# web forms application, and recently I got this error on my project. But the same project is running fine on all my colleagues' machines. Is there any problem with my laptop? I am running windows 10 pro x64. Anybody have some idea?

Error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor,
> Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your project or restoring your nuget packages?

Comment: Yes I've tried all, but doesn't work.

Comment: One of the assemblies your reference is dependent on System.Web.WebPages.Razor dll. Reference the dll in your project, it should be under one of the NuGet packages. Rebuilld and test.